# How to add a function in js to a html element - which only made in js?

Tags: javascript, css, function, html-select

I would like to change a row's background-color in a table, if I select an object of a "select"'s list, but only if this element, which is a number is even.
But the main problem is that the "object" is made in js, so that is not in the html file, so I couldn't add to the objects an onclick function, which could make the background-color of the row change.
Please help, I've lost.

HTML:

```
        <select class = "form-select, col-6" id="quantiti" onclick = "ifSelectedLetHeadChange()" >
        <!--
        This was the original version that I copied:
        <select class="form-select, col-6" id="quantiti" 
        onclick="ifSelectedLetHeadChange($(this).val())">
        -->
        </select>
```

JS:

```
        function quantity(amount) {
                var select = document.getElementById('quantiti');
            for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
                select.options[select.options.index] = i+1 ;
                select.options[select.options.onclick]="ifSelectedOptionLetTrChange()";
            }
        }
        quantity(10000);

        function ifSelectedOptionLetTrChange(value) {
            if (option.value % 2 ) {
                $("tr").css("background-color", "lightblue");
        } else {
                $("tr").css("background-color", "blue");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` to attach an event listener to your `<select>` element.

Comment: Thanks for helping! :)
But unfortunately it doesn't work :(
I strongly suspect that I do it in a wrong way...:
```
document.getElementsByTagName("object").addEventListener("select", function(ifSelectedOptionLetTrChange) {
    $("tr").css("background-color", "lightblue");
});
```

Comment: If you look at your browser console you’ll know what the issue is. You’re returning a node list so you need to iterate through them. Since you’re using jQuery why not use `$('#quantiti').change(…)`? To sniff out the selected option value you can just access the value of the select element.

Comment: It's not the #quantiti , to which I would like to add a function, but to the options in it. I mean, the table's row's style need to be changed, when I select an option in the select list.
And I even don't know, what to write into the brackets here: change(…) .
Honestly, I am taking a web-developer course, but with the JS part I am far behind. 
And I have to solve asap some sub-examination task.
Of corse I keep watching videos, looking for solutions in documentations, but in this case I couldn't find a solution - with explanation -, so I ended up here,hoping I can get some help.Thanx a lot!

Comment: Yes, but that's how select work: whenever you change an option in it, it will trigger the `change` and `input` events on the `<select>` element itself, and the `value` property of the element will reflect the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are working with JQuery. You can do it with plain JS or with JQuery.

### JQuery

It is advised to work with the change event instead of a click event. The change event however will only trigger on a change. I will do it with the change for this.

```
var select = $("#quantiti");
var tr = $("tr");

select.on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  setTrColor(value);
});

function setTrColor(value) {
  tr.css("background-color", value % 2 ? "lightblue" : "blue");
}
```

### Javascript

```
var select = document.getElementsById("quantiti");
var tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("tr"));

select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var value = targetElement.value;
  setTrColor(value);
});

function setTrColor(value) {
  tr.forEach(function(element){
    element.style.backgroundColor = value % 2 ? "lightblue" : "blue";
  });
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, if someone awnsered a question to your liking you can always give the check mark. This makes it easyer for other people to find a correct awnser

Comment: Done! Thanks again!